# How to clone links from a sibling list into another list respectivly

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, clone, each

I have a slideshow with a setup a setup similar to this

```
<div class="thumbnails">
    <li><a></a></li>
    <li><a></a></li>
    <li><a></a></li>
    <li><a></a></li>
</div>
... more HTML code
<div class="article">
    <li class="headline" ><a>A headline</a></li>
</div>
<div class="article">
    <li class="headline"><a>A headline</a></li>
</div>
<div class="article">
    <li class="headline"><a>A headline</a></li>
</div>
<div class="article">
    <li class="headline"><a>A headline</a></li>
</div>
<div class="article">
    <li class="headline"><a>A headline</a></li>
</div>
```

I have tried some jQuery like this

```
$j(".article").each(function () {
$j(this).find(".headline a")clone().appendTo( ".thumbnails li a" );
});
```

but this just produces a sibling list of all `.headline a` items in each `.thumbnails li a`

How would I clone each of an un-nested list into each of it's corresponding thumbnail a tag?

Comment: Your markup is invalid, `li` should be child of an `ul`/`ol` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.article .headline a').each(function(i) {
    $(this).clone().appendTo($('.thumbnails li').eq(i));
});
```

So you're iterating over `a`s in article and then cloning it in an `n-th` `li` in thumbnails.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BEy3U/

Answer (score -1):

i think the right way to do this:

```
$(".article").each(function () {
    $( ".thumbnails" ).append( $(this).html() );
});
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.